# How to change settings to import MetalPerformanceShaders in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, metal

I have developed an app with the MetalPerformanceShaders framework and now I am trying to use the same code in another application. The new app does not allow me to import the framework? I imagine it is to do with the frameworks feature availability(https://developer.apple.com/metal/availability/).

Is there anyway of decreasing the compatibility of the app but so that it allows the MetalPerformanceShaders framework?

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans  no such module 'MetalPerformanceShaders'

Comment: Are you certain you're compiling for a physical device or a Generic Device? Metal (and by extension, MPS) is not supported in the Simulator.

Comment: Yes I am sure. It won't let me import the framework. as soon as I type it in, I get an error.

Comment: Did you set the deployment target of the project to iOS 10 or later?

Answer (score 1):

Adding @available(iOS 10.0, *) before every class, function and struct that uses MPS solves the problem.

Comment: I should think that setting the minimum iOS for the app in Xcode to iOS 10 or 11 would be simpler.